# Query limits for day reached

Tags: gracenote

I have been testing an application I am developing using the webapi, and I have started to get the following error message:

```
GCSP: Hello error: [1010] The Gracenote ODP 15822 [Name: *registered-name*]
[App: *registered-app*] application has reached is daily lookup limit with
Gracenote. You may try again tomorrow or may contact Gracenote support at
support@gracenote.com.
[Gracenote Error: <ERR>]
```

The application I am developing is looking up track details and cover artwork for songs being streamed from Mood/Pandora for Business service. It is making approximately one call for each song, so something like 15 searches per hour on average. I may have done more during testing, but not a lot more.

Once completed, I would expect this service to make fewer than 500 searches per day per location, and for it initially to be used at 4 locations.

What are the lookup limits I am running into?

What are my options to get a higher lookup limit?

Thanks

Comment: It tells you what you need to do: `contact Gracenote support at
support@gracenote.com`

Comment: Yes Alan, I contacted them before posting here and they shuffled me off to this forum.

Comment: That's weird. An automated reply, perhaps? I don't think the forum will help you resolve the issue with the query limit.